# Download .csv file from mail attachemnt and save in DocumentDirectory of my app

Tags: ios, sqlite, csv, uiwebview

In my application, I need to populate my `sqlite database` using a `csv` file.

Until now, I have thought to proceed in the following way-

1. Because user cannot browse to pick files in ios (due to
   `"sandboxing"` of app), I will ask the user to download `csv` file from
   email
2. For this, the user needs to have a third party app that will
   allow him to download the csv file
3. The mail will be opened in `UIWebView` (using `mailto:`); and when
   the user downloads the csv file, I will save it to the
   `DocumentsDirectory` of my app.
4. The csv file will be parsed and `sqlite DB` will be populated.

Is it the correct way I am following??

However; I am still stuck at square1..!!

I cannot find an application that will allow user to download a `CSV` file.

Also, I cannot find a way to save an email attachment directly into my `DocumentsDirectory.`

Comment: Why not just register you app to open CSV files, then any app will be able to send CSV file to your app. Like the default mail app, dropbox, etc..

Comment: Ok.. Never thought of this.. let me try this and get back to you..

Comment: Heyy.. Through this, I will be able to read the file, but will I be able to save it in the DocumentsDirectory of app?

Comment: Yes, you will be able to copy the file into the document directory once the user select your app to open the file. [Opening Supported File Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/filemanagement/conceptual/documentinteraction_topicsforios/Articles/OpeningSupportedFileTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010412-SW1)

Comment: Ok.. Thanks.. Will try and let you know the results..